# "Matizador" aqui significa "corante"?

Tags: significado-em-contexto

Quero me assegurar do significado de *matizador* no texto seguinte:

> Shampoo **matizador** que promove uma limpeza suave e combate os tons amarelados dos cabelos loiros, grisalhos, brancos, fios ou mechas em processos de descoloração. Suas propriedades nutritivas, antioxidantes, emolientes e revitalizantes, conferem maior maleabilidade, maciez e brilho radiante ao loiro desejado.

É corar/dar cor, não é? É que a palavra tem outras definições.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vamos começar pela definição de Matizar:

> **Significado de Matizar**
>
> verbo transitivo
>
> Fazer passar gradualmente de um matiz a outro: a arte de matizar as
> cores.
>
> [Figurado] Expressar diferenças delicadas: matizar as palavras. verbo
> pronominal Apresentar cores variadas: os jardins matizam-se de flores
> na primavera.

Resumidamente, seria trocar cor gradualmente.
Porém, nesse caso é um termo bem específico de uma área e quem poderia responder essa pergunta é alguém mais técnico em cabelos.

Mesmo assim pesquisei e acredito que a melhor definição seria um processo de **correção da tonalidade do cabelo**. Esse processo é indicado principalmente em dois casos: pela ação do tempo ou exposição dos cabelos a piscina e etc, que acaba mundando o tom (cor) do cabelo tingido. Ou corrigir alguma tonalidade.

> Quem busca pelo uso do matizador, quer neutralizar as cores.
> Utilizando o processo de neutralização, retirarmos cores indesejadas
> dos cabelos, nesse caso em especial das luzes. Um exemplo muito
> clássico de matização para neutralizar nuance é a que se faz na
> finalização das luzes.

Fonte: [Nação Verde](http://www.nacaoverde.com.br/nacao-saudavel/o-que-e-matizador-saiba-o-por-que-ele-desamarela-cabelos-loiros/)

> A matização é um processo que traz muitos benefícios para os cabelos
> que já possuem tintura, já que auxilia tanto na manutenção da cor,
> quanto na obtenção do tom desejado. Ela permite que os fios coloridos
> — não importando qual seja a cor — possam ser realçados, ficando com
> um tom muito mais brilhante, luminoso e vivo. Por exemplo: no caso dos
> cabelos loiros, é comum que, com a ação do tempo e de agentes
> externos, como o sol, a piscina ou a água do mar, a cor acabe ficando
> amarelada, alaranjada e, até mesmo, esverdeada! A matização ajuda a
> recuperar o tom original desses fios, fazendo assim com que você não
> precise passar novamente uma tintura.
>
> **Matização e coloração são a mesma coisa?**
>
> Não! Essa é uma pergunta que
> muitas pessoas que não conhecem o processo costumam fazer. A coloração
> é uma técnica para mudar toda a cor do cabelo. Por exemplo: você tem o
> cabelo castanho claro e quer deixá-lo preto azulado, então, usa uma
> tinta que seja dessa cor. Já a matização, como dissemos acima, tem
> mais a função de corrigir a cor do cabelo que já possui coloração e o
> processo pode, inclusive, ser feito em diversos momentos — antes ou
> bem depois da coloração —, dependendo do objetivo que você tem em
> mente. Então, antes de optar por um ou por outro, avalie quais são
> seus objetivos e converse com um profissional para entender qual
> processo é o mais indicado para você.

Fonte: [Beleza com Inteligência](http://blog.aneethun.com/matizar-os-cabelos-por-que-e-como-fazer/)

Comment: Obrigada! Aprecio muito seu tempo, sua pesquisa e sua resposta. Então, matizar aqui significa, mais ou menos, corrigir/modificar a cor/tonalidade do cabelo para manter a cor original, certo? Obrigada.

Comment: Não exatamente a cor original. Pode ser um cabelo tingido que com o passar do tempo ou fatores externos como piscina e sol, mudou o tom.

Comment: Sim, sim, eu me referia a isso também, mas parece que me exprimi mal. rs Obrigada. :)